# how to find all $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n(n+1)\mid(n-1)! $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

how to find all $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n(n+1)\mid(n-1)! $

Comment: A brute force search gave $8$, $9$, $14$, $15$ and then all integers greater or equal to $20$ (at least up to 1,000,000) ... You might want to investigate on that ;)

Comment: @Dolma: So $23 \mid 22!$?

Comment: Well, no since the question is not $n|(n-1)!$ but $n(n+1)|(n-1)!$

Comment: @Dolma So $(23*24) \,|\, 22!$?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit quick on that one. I guess there was some rounding error on Matlab that made him think those were divisors ... my mistake :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Here $n|(n-1)!$ for all $n$ being composite and $n>4$. And $n$ and $n+1$ are **not** primes.

Proof that $n|(n-1)!$ if $n>4$ is composite is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/if-n-is-composite-then-n-divides-n-1).

$(n-1)!=(n-1)(n-2) \cdots 1$. You need to have sufficient factors in $\{n-1,n-2 ,\cdots 1\}$to cancel out both $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: $3$ is not a divisor of $2!=2$, $4$ is not a divisor of $3!=6$, ...

Comment: *Positive* $\to$ *Composite* (I was in parallel universe)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I saw your edit after I posted my comment ;)

Comment: Your first statement is still wrong. Hint: $4$.

Comment: If $n=r\cdot p^2,$ can $n$ divide $(n-1)!$

Comment: @Inceptio: I said "*Your first statement is still wrong.*" where your first statement is "*Here $n|(n−1)!$ for all $n$ being composite.*"

Comment: Note also that $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime, so do not share any common factors, so divisibility can be tested separately for $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Doesn't it? We have enough factors in $(n-1)!$ to cancel out $n$?

Comment: @TMM: Does it suffice the condition now?

Comment: @Inceptio, agreed. Sorry,for the confusion.