# $(n-1)! \equiv \text{?} \bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have problems solving the following equation:

$$(n-1)! \equiv \text{ ?} \pmod n$$

I already know it cannot be $-1$ (by Wilson's theorem).

I've tried checking what the solutions can be for small values of $n$:

$n=2: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 1 \equiv  \ \ 2k+1 \ \ \ \ \bmod  2, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$
$n=3: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 2 \equiv  \ \ 3k+2 \ \ \ \bmod  3, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$
$n=4: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 6 \equiv  \ \ 4k+2 \ \ \ \ \bmod  4, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$
$n=5: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 24 \equiv  \ \ 5k+4 \ \bmod 5, \ \  k \in \mathbb{N}$
$n=6: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 120 \equiv  \ \ 0 \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \bmod 6, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$
$n=7: \ \ \ \ (n-1)! = 720 \equiv  \ \ 7k+6 \ \bmod 7, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$

but I can't see any relationship here. Could you help me here?

Thank you.

Comment: The numbers which you checked contains $2$ composites and all others are primes. You should have tried for more numbers to see the pattern.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For primes, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (\mod p)$, [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

And note that $(n-1)! \equiv 0(\mod n)$ for all $n$ being composite greater than $4$. You will see the similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381273/how-to-find-all-n-in-bbb-n-such-that-nn1-midn-1/381284#381284) and proof for $n \in$ composite is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/if-n-is-composite-then-n-divides-n-1).

Comment: Just to make sure: Is what I wrote for $n \ = \ 4$ correct? Should I write $4k+2$ or just $2$ ? In case $n=1$ we have $(n-1)! = 1 \equiv 0 $ (mod 1), is that right?

Comment: @Sandy: You just write $2$(*The remainder*). For example $50 \equiv 50 (\mod 100)$

Answer (score 4):

HINT: When $n$ is prime, you can use [Wilson’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). When $n$ is composite and greater than $4$, show that $n\mid(n-1)!$.

Comment: $4$ is composite and greater than $2$, but $4\not\mid 6$

Comment: Apparently composite should be greater than $4$. Cause: $4 \not | 6$. Cause you have no *two* $2$ factors before the number $4$.

Comment: @Inceptio: Thanks; that was a genuine typo.