# Proving Wilson's theorem for $n=11$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Wilson's theorem establishes that if a $n$ number is prime then:
\begin{align}
(n-1)! &\equiv -1\ \textrm{mod}\ (n)
\end{align}

I have probed the theorem for the particular case where $n = 7$ like this:

I first consider the set $\{2,..,n-2\}$, in my case, $\{2,3,4,5\}$ and then I take the pair of numbers $a$ and $a¹$ where:

\begin{align}
2.4 &\equiv 1\ \textrm{mod}\ (7)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
3.5 &\equiv 1\ \textrm{mod}\ (7)
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
2.3.4.5 &\equiv 1\ \textrm{mod}\ (7)
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
6 &\equiv -1\ \textrm{mod}\ (7)
\end{align}
And finally,
\begin{align}
6! &\equiv -1\ \textrm{mod}\ (7)
\end{align}

How can I prove the theorem where $n=11$? How can I retrieve $a$ and $a¹$?

Comment: Observe that $8$ divides $r!$ for $r\ge4$

Comment: $2\cdot4\equiv0\pmod8$, so what about $7!=7\cdot6\cdot5\cdots$?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/if-n-is-composite-then-n-divides-n-1

Comment: Please don't change the question after it was already answered!

Comment: $2\cdot 6 = 12;\, 3\cdot 4 = 12;\, 5\cdot 9 = 45;\, 7\cdot 8 = 56$.

Comment: It was a mistake to put $n=8$, i really meant $n=11$. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to Old Question**

You can't prove the statement when $n=8$ because it's false. Note $7!$ is $0$ mod $8$.

Wilson's theorem is in fact an if and only if statement. The proposition $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$ is true if and only if $n$ is prime.

**Answer to Edit**

To answer your new question, use the pairs $(1,10)$, $(2,6)$, $(3,4)$, $(5,9)$, and $(7,8)$.

Comment: because $7! = 7 \times ... \times 4 \times ... \times 2 $

Comment: @what'sup Indeed.

Comment: Note: the OP has changed the ... P

Comment: is the pair $(1,10)$ correct? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Wilson's Theorem is true **if and only if** $n$ is prime. You cannot prove it for composite $n$.

Comment: You can certainly probe this statement for composite $n$, but you can't prove it.

Comment: OK, $\text{prove}\ne\text{probe}$. Thanks! :P