# Is there a composite integer $n \geq 9$ such that $n \nmid (n-1)!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a composite integer $n \geq 9$ such that $n \nmid (n-1)!$?

If we are not talking about composites then by Wilson's theorem we have $n \nmid (n-1)!$.

Comment: There is not even one for $n>4$

Comment: $6 \mid 5!$, I am afraid.

Comment: But you are looking for $n$ that does not divide $(n-1)!$.

Comment: Yeah, right. How to prove this? I said $6 \mid 5!$ because you said "there is not even one for $n > 4$". There does exist such $n$ if $n > 4,$ viz $n=6$. :)

Comment: consider $n = ab$, Notice that $ a \lt n$ and $b \lt  n$  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/if-n-is-composite-then-n-divides-n-1

Comment: @Comeseeconquer: From `9` to `10^5`, there is no such that number. I examined it. So we have to prove it probably.

Comment: It is obvious that any prime $p$ dividing composite $n$ also divides $(n-1)!$. The question is how to prove that if $p^r$ divides $n$, then it also divides $(n-1)!$. So you need some kind of lower bound on the number dividing $(n-1)!$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n>4$ is composite, then either $n=p^2$ for a prime number $p>2$ (and thus $2p<p\cdot p=n$) or you can find two *different* numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ with $n_1 n_2 = n$ and $n_1,n_2>1$ in which case clearly $n_1,n_2\leq n-1$.

In the first case $p$ and $2p$ are two different factors of $(n-1)!$, in the second case $n_1$ and $n_2$ are.

**Clarification:** With *two different factors* I obviously meant that $p$ and $2p$ or $n_1$ and $n_2$ are two different members of $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ (and not two arbitrary divisors of $(n-1)!$ which would not suffice).

Comment: That's not sufficient to conclude that the product of these two numbers $n$ also divides $(n-1)!$.

Comment: @WimC: I've added a clarification to my answer which hopefully makes clear what I intended to say.

Comment: Thanks.  That *is* neat. +1.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me that my wording was ambiguous!