# To find all integers $n > 1$ for which $(n-1)!$ is a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> To find all integers $n > 1$ for which $(n-1)!$ is a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z_n$. (Gallian Problem)

$\mathbb Z_n$ does not contain any zero divisors when $n$ is a prime number. So we look at the composite numbers.

For $\mathbb Z_4$ we have $(n-1)!$ as $3! =6$ which is equal to $\bar 2$ and it is a zero divisor.

For $\mathbb Z_6$ we have $(n-1)!$ as $5! =120$ which is equal to $\bar 0$ and it is not a zero divisor.

For $\mathbb Z_8$  we have $(n-1)!$ as $7! =5040$ which is equal to $\bar 0$ and it is not a zero divisor.

We Know if $n$ is composite, then $n$ divides $(n-1)!$ when $n \geq 6$.

Thus the only $n$ for which $(n-1)!$ is a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z_n$ is $n =4$.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: *"if $n$ is composite, then $n$ divides $(n−1)!$."* Why this is true? I assume you mean $n \geq 6.$ If you can prove this, then you are done.

Comment: yes i assumed that

Comment: A proof of this fact can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/164852/39599).

Answer (score 1):

0 is a zero-divisor. This means that the statement is true for every composite number by a similar argument to yours. (Reply to comment below: I looked it up on Wikipedia.  Appearantly different sources use different definitions. Annoying)

If you change the question to involve non-zero zero divisors, your solution is correct.

However, you may be asked to prove "We Know if n is composite, then n divides (n−1)! when n≥6."  It is true, but can you prove it?

Comment: Zero is never a zero divisor..

Comment: I'm copying this from the first algebra textbook I studied in: "Let $A$ be a ring. A element $a \in A$ is said to be a zero divisor if $a \neq 0_A$ and there exists $b \in A$, such that $b \neq 0_A$ and $ab = 0_A$". I guess I had been misled.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is a prime then $\mathbb Z_n$ is a field and therefore has no non-zero zero divisors.
If $n$ is not a prime we may write $n = ab$ where both $a$ and $b$ are less than $n$.
If $a \ne b$, then $(n − 1)!$ includes both $a$ and $b$ among its factors
so $(n − 1)! = 0$.
If $a = b$ and $a > 2$, then $(n − 1)! = (a^2 − 1)(a^2 − 2)\cdots(a^2 − a)\cdots
(a^2 − 2a)\cdots 2 · 1$.
Since this product includes $a^2 = n$, it is $0$. The only remaining case is
$n = 4$ and in this case $3! = 2$ is a zero divisor.