# Leibniz theorem : A natural number $p> 2$ is prime iff $(p - 2)!-1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory, congruences, primality-test

I thought of using Wilson's theorem for the proof.

First we have by Wilson's theorem 
$$(p - 1)!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
We can write this as 
$$(p - 2)!(p-1)+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$(p - 2)!(p-1)+1=p(p-2)!-[(p-2)!-1]$$
Hence the right side p(p-2)! is divisible by p also the other term is divisible by p. So we have
$$(p - 2)!-1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You know wilson's theorem? Use that.

Comment: An equivalent statement is widely (and probably unreasonably) known as Wilson's Theorem. A search will yield many hits.

Comment: see here https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/Wilsons.html

Comment: The proof is trivial, you  simply invoke that there is a primitive element x, so that the numbers you need to multiply will be given by the powers of x. You need to omit p-1, but that's -1 so, you multiply by -1.

Comment: For the direction that the congruence fails when $p$ is composite, see [this earlier Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/if-n-is-composite-then-n-divides-n-1).

Comment: $(p-1)!$ multiplied by $(p-2)$ isn't $(p-2)!$.

Comment: is this better? @Wojowu

Comment: Yes, it seems all-right to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is very simple:
first by Wilson theorem:
$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
with $p$ prime, now we add $p$ to the right side:
$$(p-1)(p-2)! \equiv (p-1) \pmod p$$
since $gcd(p-1,p)=1$ by cancellation law we can cancel $(p-1)$ on both sides
$$(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
$$(p-2)!-1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$