# Find $n$ for which $\frac{(n!)^2-(n+2)!}{(n+1)!}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

I think there is no integer $n$ for which the above expression is an integer, but I am not sure.

Comment: For $n=0$ the expression is an integer

Comment: It is an integer for $n=5,7,8,9,11,13,14,15,17,19,20,\dots$. Indeed it is an integer for all $n\ge5$ such that $n+1$ is not prime (which are the integers for which $n+1$ divides $n!$.

Answer (score 6):

With a little bit of work, you can show that

$$\frac{(n!)^2-(n+2)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)} - (n+2)$$

so any $n$ for which $(n+1)$ divides $n!$ is a solution.

See Greg Martin's comment above.

Comment: You mean $n+1$ divides $n! $.  I think it is a typo!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Note that $n+1\mid n!$ iff $n+1$ is not prime (see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164852)). Cheers!

Comment: @barto Yes! which has been pointed out by Greg Martin above.